# Subgroups of $\operatorname{PGL}_n$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, orthogonal-groups, classical-groups, normal-subgroups

As algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field $K$ of characteristic not $2$, $\operatorname{GO}_{2n}$ is a closed normal subgroup of the conformal orthogonal group $\operatorname{CO}_{2n}$. Is the projective conformal orthogonal group $\operatorname{PCO}_{2n}$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{PGO}_{2n}$? Is $\operatorname{PCO}_{2n}$ a maximal subgroup of $\operatorname{PGL}_{2n}$? Same questions for the odd degree $2n+1$.  I am lacking of tools to analyze this. Thank you.

Edit:

$\operatorname{GO}(V)=\{g\in \operatorname{GL}(V)\ | \ f(g(v),g(w))=f(v,w) \,\   \forall v,w \in V\}$ for a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form on $V$. And $\operatorname{CO}_{2n}$ preserves the form up to a scalar.

Comment: I would recommend you to explain your notations. I know what ${\rm PGL}_{2n}$ is. What are the other groups?

Comment: Thanks. Doing it now.

Comment: Your definition of $GO(V)$ is what I would have called the orthogonal group $O_V$.

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "ag.algebraic-geometry". I added this tag now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\O}{{\rm O}} 
\newcommand{\GO}{{\rm GO}} 
\newcommand{\PO}{{\rm PO}}
\newcommand{\PGO}{{\rm PGO}}
\newcommand{\GL}{{\rm GL}}
\newcommand{\PGL}{{\rm PGL}}
\newcommand{\SL}{{\rm SL}}
\newcommand{\SO}{{\rm SO}}
\newcommand{\Id}{{\rm Id}}
$**Notation.**
$K$ is an algebraically closed field;

$V$ a finite-dimensional vector space over $K$;

$f\colon V \times V\to K$ a non-degenerate symmetric bilinear form.

We write
\begin{align*} 
\O(V,f)&=\{g\in\GL(V)\ |\ g^*f=f\},\\
\GO(V,f)&=\{g\in\GL(V)\ |\ g^*f =\lambda f \ \ \text{for some}\ \lambda\in K^\times\}.
\end{align*}
Here
$$(g^*f)(v_1,v_2)=f (g\cdot v_1,g\cdot v_2)\ \ \text{for}\ v_1,v_2\in V.$$
We set
\begin{align*} 
\PO(V,f)&=\O(V,f)/\{\pm1\},\\
\PGO(V)&=\GO(V,F)/K^\times \subset \PGL(V).
\end{align*}

> **Proposition.** $\PO(V,f)\cong\PGO(V,f)$.

*Proof.* We have the inclusion homomorphism
$$ i\colon \O(V,f)\hookrightarrow \GO(V,f)$$
which induces a homomorphism
$$i_*\colon \PO(V,f)\to  \PGO(V,f),\quad\ g\cdot\{\pm1\}\mapsto g\cdot K^\times.$$
We show that $i_*$ is an isomorphism.

Let $g\cdot\{\pm1\}\in\ker i_*\,$. Then
$$g\in(K^\times\cdot\Id_V)\cap\O(V,f)=\{\pm1\}=1\cdot \{\pm1\}.$$
This $i_*$ is injective.

Let $g\cdot K^\times\in\PGO(V,f)$.
Then $ g^*f =\lambda f$ for some $\lambda\in K^\times$.
We set $g'=g/\sqrt{\lambda}$ (recall that $K$ is algebraically closed).
Then $(g')^*f=f$, whence $g'\in\O(V,f)$.
Thus
$$g\in \O(V,f)\cdot K^\times,$$
whence $i_*$ is surjective, which completes the proof of the proposition.

Concerning maximality, it is well-known that $\SO(V,f)$ is maximal in $\SL(V)$;
see, for instance [YCor's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3525094/37763) to [$\operatorname{SO}(n)$ is an (abstractly) maximal subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3523489/operatornameson-is-an-abstractly-maximal-subgroup-of-operatornamesl/3525094#3525094)
in Math.StackExchange.com in the case $K=\Bbb R$.
As above, one can deduce the maximality of $\PGO(V,f)$ in $\PGL(V)$ by standard methods.
If you cannot do that yourself, ask in MathStackExchange.com;
your question seems to be more suitable for that forum rather than for MathOverflow.

Comment: MathJax is very poor at ignoring whitespace one would expect, so it is necessary that the `$` that ends the command block be adjacent to the **Notation** at the beginning of the post to avoid a spurious space.  I have edited accordingly.