# Centraliser of a finite group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, vector-spaces, classical-groups

Let $G=\operatorname{Sp}(8,K)$ be a symplectic algebraic group over an algebraically closed field of characteristic not $2$.

We have a vector space decomposition $V_8=V_2\otimes V_4$ where the $2$-dimensional space $V_2$ has an alternating form and the $4$-dimensional space $V_4$ has a symmetric form.

Let $Q_8\le \operatorname{Sp}(2,K)\le G$ be a quaternion subgroup and
$$Q_8=\langle 
\begin{pmatrix} w&0\\ 0&w^{-1} \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ -1&0 \end{pmatrix}
\rangle.$$
$w\in K$ has order $4$.

Let $\operatorname{CO}$ be the conformal orthogonal group preserving a symmetric bilinear form up to a scalar and $\operatorname{GO}$ be the orthogonal group preserving a symmetric bilinear form.

Question:

Is there an element $e\otimes I_2$ in $C_G(Q_8\otimes I_4)$ such that $e\in \operatorname{CO}(4,K) \setminus \operatorname{GO}(4,K)$?

I tried to construct it myself. But so far no success.

Comment: Do you mean $Q_8 \otimes I_2$, if you want $e$ to be $4\times 4$?

Comment: Thank you for the input. I think I mean: $e\otimes I_2 \in C_G(Q_8\otimes I_4)$ such that $e\in CO\setminus GO$.

Comment: As discussed in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455439/subgroups-of-operatornamepgl-n#comment1179150_455439) by @BenMcKay on your other question, what you call $\operatorname{GO}$ is what most people would just call $\operatorname O$.  It would probably be a good idea to recall the definition each time.

Comment: Thank you. I think I've included the definition in the question...

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455625/centraliser-of-a-finite-group#comment1179623_455625), it is up to you.  You say it in words, but, if I hadn't already read your previous question, then I would have skimmed over it and just proceeded on the basis of my understanding of what $\operatorname{GO}$ means.  But perhaps I am atypical. \\ I also realise that I do not understand your question.  You ask whether a certain kind of element of $G = \operatorname{Sp}(8, K)$ belongs to $\operatorname{CO}(4, K)$.  How can it?

Comment: OK. Let me rearrange the order of appearance. Thank you still.

Comment: With your re-wording, the question makes more sense, except that you consider $Q_8 \otimes I_4$ as a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sp}(2, K) \times \operatorname{Sp}(4, K)$, and then ask for $e \otimes I_2$ to be an element of that; so I assume that you mean $I_2 \otimes e$.  But every element $I_2 \otimes e$ commutes with $Q_8 \otimes I_4$, so you seem just to be asking whether $I_2 \otimes e$ can be symplectic if $e$ is conformal but not orthogonal.  But $I_2 \otimes e$ scales the symplectic form by the same factor by which $e$ scales the bilinear pairing, so it seems no, right?

Comment: Is it possible that for the two forms $f_1, f_2$ on $V_2, V_4$, the two scalars are inverse to each other, resulting in the tensor form $f=f_1\otimes f_2$ having a scalar of 1? And this might give something from the conformal group? I am confused, sorry...

Comment: @user488802 You should define an injection $CO(4)\hookrightarrow Sp(8)$ for this question to make sense. What you sketch is a map $\{(g,h)\in CO(4)\times CSp(2):\mu(g)=\mu(h)^{-1}\}$ where $\mu$ is the similitude character (with kernel $\{(xI_4,yI_2)\in CO(4)\times CSp(2):x^2=y^{-2}\}$). However, I do not see how to define an injection $CO(4)\hookrightarrow Sp(8)$ from this.

Comment: @KentaSuzuki  Thanks for the input. Would you be able to elaborate more? I'm not quite familiar with similitude character. By "a map", you mean a map from $CO(4)\times CSp(2)$ to ....? Thanks.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1179682), it is certainly possible, but you asked that $f_1$ be $I_2$, whose scaling factor is $1$. [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1179743), the value of the similitude character is the scalar by which the automorphism of $V$ scales the relevant form.  The map you describe is from the fibre product (in your notation) $\operatorname{CO}(4) \times_{\operatorname{GL}_1} \operatorname{CSp}(2)$ to $\operatorname{Sp}(8)$.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for the input. So what is Kenta Suzuki's conclusion, then? I'm confused. Is it the following:  If I have such an injection, then there is the "map" from the fibre product to $Sp(8)$. But since we can't define such an injection, the centralizer cannot be $CO(4)$...

Comment: @LSpice  My $Q_8$ can actually be from $CSp(2)$, So I guess $f_1$ doesn't have to be $I_2$? Thanks.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455625/centraliser-of-a-finite-group#comment1179779_455625), it is up to you what you want your question to ask, but currently it asks for $f_1 = I_2$.  If you want to drop that requirement, then what you ask is easy; you can take $f_1$ and $f_2$ to be multiplication by inverse scalars.  But I suspect that's not what you want, so maybe it's worth taking some time to think about what you *do* want.